# Why aren't my href links working?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation

I'm a little new to web programming and have looked far and wide trying to fix this problem on my own but for the life of me I cannot figure it out, I greatly appreciate any and all help.

I'm basically making a navigation bar and I attempt to have it link to my other html pages but it's not working. I use the following code.

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="banner"> <!-- contains main banner and logo -->
    <a href="index.html" id="logo">
        <img src="images/newlogo.png" alt="blahblah">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-bar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#slideshow">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
    border-top: 12px solid #9e2630;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    height: 115px;
    margin-bottom: 130px;
}

header #logo img {
    padding-top: 35px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

header ul {
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    min-height: 60px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

header ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    left:-50%;
    /*height: 45px;*/
}

header ul li a {
    font: normal normal normal 18px/20px 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #9e2630;
    /*height: 43px;*/
}

header .nav li a:hover{
    background-color: #9e2630; color:#FFFFFF;
}

header ul li a.current{
    background-color: #9e2630; color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

The link in the logo works fine. The link in the contact also work fine, there's no problem when I link to an element on the page. The other four links do not work. I've also tried setting the href to an "http" address but that didn't work either. I've run all of these tests in DreamWeaver's browser preview function (IE and Chrome) as well as on a remote server with no difference in results.

I also noticed the z-index in the header is set to 200 (this is sample code I'm working with) which I understand plays a role in how elements are layered. I tried fiddling with that to no avail. What do you guys think?

Edit1: here's what my file structure looks like

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWbPw.jpg)

Also here's the template I've been using

[template](http://www.templatemo.com/preview/templatemo_399_tamarillo)

Edit2: Ok guys I found the problem was a JS file called jquery.singlePageNav.min.js

unfortunately when I disable this file I lose the nice image slider I had on my web page but the links work again, so now I have to fix that :p

Thanks for your help everybody!

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Wz7Wu/ . Have you tried with just this CSS and HTML? Is there some JavaScript function blocking the click event?

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4Ppx/) suggests that there is no problem with this specific piece of code. Something else is blocking your links. Do you have an element overlay? Perhaps some JavaScript? Do you even see the cursor change as you move over the links?

Comment: You say: 'Why aren't my href links working?' So I assume the links are displayed but when you click on them you do not get a page?

Comment: @smartmeta Please read the question, not just the title.

Comment: I did. But did not get what is not working.

Comment: Or are you saying the links work, but don't go to the page you think they should? Could you tell us a little more about your directory/routing structure?

Comment: Is your browser support HTML 5 ?

Comment: Thank everybody for the replies, @lc yes it worked for me in jfiddle as well (though not with http addresses, idk if thats normal?). The code I'm using came with a bunch of js scripts so it's possible that it's blocking the links somehow. The code I'm using with can be found [here](http://www.templatemo.com/preview/templatemo_399_tamarillo).  I'll post a picture of my file structure

Comment: @SecondRikudo The cursor does change and the links also change color as per the a:hover CSS code. I have been wondering about element overlay but I'm unsure how to know for certain if that's the problem.

Comment: @smartmeta yes you are correct, the links are displayed but they don't change to a new html page. Mean while the img link does change to a new page while using a similar href address.

Comment: If hover works you probably have no overlay. Try to fix your jsfiddle so that it displays you problem. Currently it isn't.

Comment: @SecondRikudo ok i made some progress. I tried my html and css alone in jsfiddle and found no issue. So I went back to my editor and tried disabling my js files one at a time. I found the error was coming from a js file called jquery.singlePageNav.min.js

Comment: @user3766321: [edit] your question to include relevant code,

Comment: @SecondRikudo I'm unsure if I should make a new topic now but the problem code come from this library https://github.com/ChrisWojcik/single-page-nav, it's intended for single page use so i think it overrides the href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [plugin's documentation](https://github.com/ChrisWojcik/single-page-nav), by default it will override *all* links, which is clearly not what you want here. However there is a `filter` option which can override this behavior:

> 'filter' - By default, the plugin will be applied to all links within the container, use this to filter out certain links using jquery's built in filter method (e.g. ':not(.external)')

Therefore I suggest adding a class to all the links you don't want to be single-page-nav-ized, then initializing with the `filter` option:

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="banner"> <!-- contains main banner and logo -->
    <a href="index.html" id="logo">
        <img src="images/newlogo.png" alt="blahblah">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-bar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="external">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="schedule.html" class="external">Schedule</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.html" class="external">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html" class="external">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#slideshow">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).singlePageNav({filter: ':not(.external)'});
```

Comment: Thank you! this is what I found out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Give proper path to your pages

```
        <li><a href="/pathtopage/index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pathtopage/schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pathtopage/register.html">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pathtopage/about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slideshow">Contact</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

be sure that all your .html pages in the correct folder. As for now you are linking to html pages in the same folder, so if you dont have them there , you wont be able to open them like this. you have to navigate to the other links from your index.html. Ill explain: if you have a folder `"sites"` and you have all your .html documents there, it should work the way you did. BUT if in your folder `"sites"` you only have your index.html and the other sites are in a subfolder `"sub-sites"` you will have to navigate there first. As posted in answer no. 1