# Hyperlink doesn't redirect while others do

Tags: templates, redirect, hyperlink

I'm having a free template from Creative Tim. [It's called Paper Kit 2 and you can find it here:](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-kit-2)

The problem I have is, when I create a hyperlink from the `<h1>` tag that read `Paper Kit 2` and the `<h2>` tag that read `Make your mark with a free bootstrap 4 UI Kit!` they aren't working. They don't redirect me to `href="https://www.creative-tim.com"`
But the buttons and icons in the top bar do bring me to the corresponding pages. The HTML code is:

```
<div class="page-header section-dark" style="background-image: url('./assets/img/antoine-barres.jpg')">
    <div class="filter"></div>
    <div class="content-center">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="title-brand">
          <a href="https://www.creative-tim.com">
            <h1 class="presentation-title">Paper Kit 2</h1>
          </a>

          <div class="fog-low">
            <img src="./assets/img/fog-low.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="fog-low right">
            <img src="./assets/img/fog-low.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="https://www.creative-tim.com">
          <h2 class="presentation-subtitle text-center">Make your mark with a Free Bootstrap 4 UI Kit! </h2>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="moving-clouds" style="background-image: url('./assets/img/clouds.png'); "></div>
    <h6 class="category category-absolute">Designed and coded by
      <a href="https://www.creative-tim.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="./assets/img/creative-tim-white-slim2.png" class="creative-tim-logo">
      </a>
    </h6>
  </div>
```

I looked it up on the stackoverflow forum and [I read something about javascript interfering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360068/why-arent-my-href-links-working). That post [refers to an issue on a GitHub page](https://github.com/ChrisWojcik/single-page-nav) but I don't understand what they explain there.

Can someone shed a light on this issue and why some hyperlinks work correct and others not (redirecting).

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/9beurtpg/).  (With the caveat that the target website refuses to display in the jsFiddle frame, but the browser at least clearly followed the link.)  Can you update the question to include a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Well, I'm an amateur and not a skilled computer engineer or coder [but I managed to put something together in jsfiddle that reproduces the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/Zakkenwasser/juc0xoya/1/). I think that gives a good impression that some hyperlinks work but 2 hyperlinks don't redirect.  This one: `<a href="https://www.creative-tim.com"><h1 class="presentation-title">Paper Kit2</h1></a>` and this one `<a href="https://www.creative-tim.com"><h2 class="presentation-subtitle text-center">Make your mark with a Free Bootstrap 4 UI Kit! </h2></a>` They don't execute and are not clickable.

Comment: [Or go to the site](https://bertverberne.eu/) then you can look at the source.

Comment: It's not the link, it's the styling of other elements.  In your browser, right-click over where you expect to find a link and select to inspect the element in the DOM explorer.  You'll see that the element being inspected is not the link, but another element that's styled to *cover* the page content.  There's a lot of content and styling to sift through so I don't have an easy solution at the moment, but that overall process is essentially your next debugging approach.

Comment: I took your recommendation to look for items that could cover and prevent  the hyperlinks to respond when clicked. First I removed all JS. That didn't solve it. Then I commented out suspicious items. And finally that worked. The culprits where the cloud items that covered the hyperlinks.[I've made a new jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zakkenwasser/5g1jcpa6/7/) where you can see what lines I commented out. Conclusion, problem identified. Now I can arrange the page in a slightly different way. Thanks for hinting me in the right direction.